# How the packed style structure map to sensor registers in driver code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have seen this styling being used in most driver codes. I am going through the driver code of BMM150 in the kernel. Here's the datasheet which shows the register maps : https://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/_tech/media/datasheets/BST-BMM150-DS001.pdf

In the code I can see this structure [[elixir]](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/magnetometer/bmc150_magn.c#L113) :

```
struct bmc150_magn_trim_regs {
    s8 x1;
    s8 y1;
    __le16 reserved1;
    u8 reserved2;
    __le16 z4;
    s8 x2;
    s8 y2;
    __le16 reserved3;
    __le16 z2;
    __le16 z1;
    __le16 xyz1;
    __le16 z3;
    s8 xy2;
    u8 xy1;
} __packed;
```

How does this map to the registers? The naming of these variables doesn't make sense to me. Can someone please help understand how this structure is being used?

Comment: `Here's the datasheet which shows the register maps` on page 22. They look like to be [read](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/magnetometer/bmc150_magn.c#L442) from register [0x5D](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/magnetometer/bmc150_magn.c#L82). The device writer could have reverse engineered some registers. Maybe look at commits history.

Comment: yes. 0x5D doesn't make sense.  That's a reserved register address. This confuses me why he is reading beyond the last valid register.

Comment: From this https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/mediatek/+/android-mediatek-sprout-3.10-marshmallow-mr1/drivers/misc/mediatek/magnetometer/bmm150/bmm150.c we can see it’s called “virtual linear accelerometer” feature. Dunno which data sheet refers to it, maybe it’s not public.